# SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (SYSTEM.AEROPUERTO_FK) - parent keys not found

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm getting the following error in on Oracle SQL Developer:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
    ALTER TABLE AEROPUERTO ADD CONSTRAINT AEROPUERTO_FK FOREIGN KEY (CODIGO_CIUDAD) REFERENCES CIUDAD(CODIGO)

Error report:
    SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (SYSTEM.AEROPUERTO_FK) - parent keys not found
    02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
    *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
               child records.
    *Action:   Obvious
```

Why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are records in `AEROPUERTO` that point to records that do not exist in `CIUDAD`.

To find out which records of `AEROPUERTO` have that kind of issue:

```
select * from AEROPUERTO where CODIGO_CIUDAD not in (select CODIGO from CIUDAD)
```

If the result set is not empty, you **do** have orphanaged records. You'll need to add the missing `CIUDAD` records in order to create the `AEROPUERTO_FK` foreign key, **or** update all the erroneous `AEROPUERTO.CODIGO_CIUDAD` to null (if this is a nullable field, but you will lose the city information for those airport records).

Answer (score 2):

remove primary key constraint from the  column in which you want to add the foreign key