# Oracle foreign key

Tags: oracle, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I need to add two constrains WORK_ADDRESS_ID and HOME_ADDRESS_ID in STAFF table references ADDRESS_ID in ADDRESS table, but it appears The TABLE operation was not successful for the following reason: ORA-02298: cannot validate (LIP12YJ.STAFF_CON) - parent keys not found
what should I do?

Comment: Is ADDRESS_ID a primary key in ADDRESS?

Comment: Here's something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702310/sql-error-ora-02298-cannot-validate-system-aeropuerto-fk-parent-keys-not-f

Comment: Please include the DDL for the tables, and the constraint-command that generated that error.

Comment: What's unclear about "*parent keys not found*"?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is data in the `STAFF` table that references an `ADDRESS_ID` that is not in the `ADDRESS` table.  Unfortunately, it's not obvious from the name of the constraint whether the problem is with the data in the `WORK_ADDRESS_ID` column or with the data in the `HOME_ADDRESS_ID` column.  But it is easy enough to check both

```
SELECT *
  FROM staff s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                      FROM address a
                     WHERE a.address_id = s.work_address_id )
```

will show you all the rows in the `STAFF` table that have a `WORK_ADDRESS_ID` that doesn't exist in the `ADDRESS` table.  Similarly,

```
SELECT *
  FROM staff s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                      FROM address a
                     WHERE a.address_id = s.home_address_id )
```

will show you all the rows in the `STAFF` table that have a `HOME_ADDRESS_ID` that doesn't exist in the `ADDRESS` table.